# What's the easiest way to format a numeric string?

Tags: c#, formatting

I have the following string: "12345678901", and I want it to be formatted as "123.456.789-01",
I'm currently doing it like this:

```
string s = "12345678901";
string formatted = Int64.Parse(s).ToString("000.000.000-00"); // = "123.456.789-01"
```

Is there a better way of doing this, can I do this directly, without having to convert the string to int and back to string again?

Comment: Have you tried inserting the symbols into the original string (keeping mind that strings are immutable and you need to save the result)?

Comment: I can't do this, cause the system is already established, and i just need to show this in one place

Comment: Yes, and I'm talking about that, too.  By "original string", I'm referring to `s` rather than the parsed `Int64` value. I know nothing about how you got `s`.

Comment: I'm getting s from a database, i just put it here so you know what the string i'm trying to format looks like, i'm not declaring it like this, it's just an example

Comment: Maybe i didn't understand what you meant, could you give me an example?

Comment: What I meant is that you have this string, `s`, and you want symbols inserted in at specific locations in it. The `String` class has an `Insert` method for that purpose. The parenthetical is a reminder that you can't just call `Insert` and expect it to change; you need to save the result. That's a common mistake.

Comment: What is for you _a better way_? Do you want a faster conversion? Do you want the shortest possible code? Or?

Comment: @madreflection i got what you're saying now, maybe i'll do this, thanks!

Comment: I imagine that anything that produces the desired result would be better than something that doesn't, but that fact the question is about "better" and not "functioning" means it hasn't even been tested/debugged.

Comment: @Steve I just wanted to know if there's a way of using .ToString("000.000.000-00") to format a string without having to convert it to an int before doing it

Comment: I think no, that format is understandable if you have a number not to format a string. However you can get better results in terms of performances if you use the approach suggested by @madreflection

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can reach your result without conversion to an integer and reformatting the integer to a string and it is even faster.

```
s = "12345678901";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
int pos = s.Length - 2;
if (pos > 0) sb.Insert(pos, "-");
pos -= 3;
while (pos > 0)
{
    sb.Insert(pos, ".");
    pos -= 3;
}
string formatted = sb.ToString();
```

This is more or less what madrereflection has told you in comments with the only difference that the example here uses StringBuilder to avoid the continuous rebuild of the string. From simple benchmark it is three times faster than the current approach but of course more code is required.

Comment: Calling that "better" is a stretch... I believe you that it is faster but original code `.ToString("000\\.000\\.000-00");` is so much more readable than that... (but indeed it is good answer to "without having to convert the string to int and back to string again" question and may as well be what OP is looking for in terms of "better")

Comment: I just thougth it was really odd to not be able to use such a simple method directly with a string, I thougth i wasn't seeing something, but from this i'm getting i should use the string.Insert() or do it like i'm already doing it, thanks guys